# Mobile sent emails don't get added disclaimer

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, content-filter

my company wanted to have a footer added to all emails based on sender's address. We have successfully implemented it based on this article https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-automatically-add-a-disclaimer-to-outgoing-emails-with-altermime-postfix-on-debian-squeeze.

Key master.cf lines are:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=dfilt:

dfilt     unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=Rq user=filter directory=/var/spool/filter null_sender= argv=/etc/postfix/autofooter -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
```

It works when we send emails from webmail or outlook, but fails when they are sent from mobile email client. The mobile sent emails arrive to their recipients but autofooter script is not called at all.

What differences can exist between webmail and mobile emails?

Comment: What do you see in the mail logs for a message that has the disclaimer added and one that doesn't? Do both types of messages follow the same route? You can check by looking at the full headers of a received message.

Comment: My bad! I screwed up with my testing... emails went through the autofooter script... I will post the solution just in case somebody gets the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that mobile emails came encoded in base 64 and altermime didn't decode b64 messages.

So we added a disclaimer-b64 argument and voilá:

```
    /usr/bin/altermime --input=in.$$ \
                   --disclaimer=/etc/postfix/footers/${from_address}.txt \
                   --disclaimer-html=/etc/postfix/footers/${from_address}.htm \
                   --disclaimer-b64=/etc/postfix/footers/${from_address}.b64 ||
                    { echo Message content rejected; echo Message content rejected >> /etc/postfix/footers/errors.log; exit $EX_UNAVAILABLE; }
```

That's all!

This solution was found by (David, waiting for his personal details to give him a really deserved credit)